# Deserialize nested Json into class with Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, deserialization

I have the following Json:

```
{
  "Setting": {
    "IsYear": true
  },
  "Durations": [
    {
      "Value": "100000000",
      "Duration": 1
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000001",
      "Duration": 2
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000002",
      "Duration": 3
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000003",
      "Duration": 5
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000004",
      "Duration": 0
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000005",
      "Duration": 8
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000006",
      "Duration": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

The class I have so far:

```
class Durations {
    IsYear = false;
    Durations = [];
}
```

And the deserialization:

```
let obj: MyObj = JSON.parse(jsonContent);
```

I'm actually struggling with deserializing and accessing the values in the resulting object.

Could please one show me how to properly deserialize the above json into the corresponding class with TypeScript and how to access the values?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to deserialize to a **class**? Why not instead define a type: `interface Durations{ IsYear: boolean; Duration: number[]; }`, and then `const durations: Durations = JSON.parse(...)`?

Comment: Didn't thouth about this way of solution, good point. The point is that I need this object to be passed to a method which executes some calculations based on the values

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to implement the serialize and deserialize method.

My exemple is manual.

```
const serializedObj: string = JSON.stringify({
  "Setting": {
    "IsYear": true
  },
  "Durations": [
    {
      "Value": "100000000",
      "Duration": 1
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000001",
      "Duration": 2
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000002",
      "Duration": 3
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000003",
      "Duration": 5
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000004",
      "Duration": 0
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000005",
      "Duration": 8
    },
    {
      "Value": "100000006",
      "Duration": 10
    }
  ]
});

interface MyObjType {
  Setting: {
    IsYear: boolean;
  };

  Durations: {
    Value: string;
    Duration: number;
  }[];
}

class MyObj {
  protected IsYear: MyObjType['Setting']['IsYear'] = false;
  protected Durations: MyObjType['Durations'] = [];

  public serialize(): string {
    return JSON.stringify({
      Setting: {
        IsYear: this.IsYear,
      },

      Durations: this.Durations,
    } as MyObjType);
  }

  public deserialize(serializedObj: string): void {
    const obj: MyObjType = JSON.parse(serializedObj);

    this.IsYear = obj.Setting.IsYear;
    this.Durations = obj.Durations;
  }
}

// --- Test

const obj = new MyObj();

obj.deserialize(serializedObj);

console.log(obj.serialize());
```

[Code snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAnAlgQwDbIF7wCYHkAjAKwC44oUwBzGAXhgCkBlfAOQDporrkAzAJ4AKAN4AoGDABEzeFCjIaU8uMmSpASQgBNeKkTKYlAK7wJMAL4Aac1IAixxKgXgIhgNrnJqteoBqGKaGUgCMAAwRkRFSNr7qDk4uYIYhXpaxaj6%20UgHoQeShUZEhMWnxjs7I4IYATGnWaVlqOYHwweFFYTWlcdIJldXkAMz1Gd5l0rn50h1FQz1x9hVJhgCso40TLXltBbNRACwL2f0r5GEbvk3%20re2dYavHzadVyeQAHJeZW1O7M-cANie5USrxSF18FnMAF0xBYAJQAbjEYkUUCQfFQwHgMAAsgIiMQACoCAAOOJ8snkimoKjSWl0%20nIhBAIHQejAyMkFmR5herjpvl%205G4NK5an5YHIYGMAFtCEhxRZ3NDkVCxMB0KgIBA8QSSDAfKTECB0cB0bgYAy9IhyPjCSTye4AORUhQ0Z3Ql3W-Se%20gwTHoBDi42m%20DmvAwSUQO364lk%20Au6N%20hgq3mSUnGQiYYBwJBoTA4ITwkWUGmGtKIOSOMBMVicUU0fjCa4wN00wW9K06G3kKAAC2QEA4PsQYzUDQm0b7g%20H0fHFhg2r1DoTSPM6ozWZzMFw8AQKAw2HgQgPBePBBIpZ4JZgADcQMhLU1QJBYCAryuSI6cQwWOwOFJfQEFPfMjxwS9iHXNIByHEce30f0P2IDh2xoeDGUQcVJFgudlleXUGGQjhoyVOEUQAegomAAFo6JgIl9ygFFX2gGBkP9MB4AAdy-Yhi15Yi9zPcCTxEws8EJaDWLZeAOHQEBqCEYjxOPYskSAA)